# Error While running Spring BOOT 1.5.10: s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization

Tags: jpa, spring-boot

While running Spring Boot application I am getting below error

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v1.5.10.RELEASE)

2018-02-10 15:27:24.209  INFO 14692 --- [           main] c.i.S.SpringBootSpringDataJpaApplication : Starting SpringBootSpringDataJpaApplication on LAPTOP-J6O7ENAD with PID 14692 (C:\Users\Srinu\Downloads\SpringBoot_SpringDataJPA\target\classes started by Srinu in C:\Users\Srinu\Downloads\SpringBoot_SpringDataJPA)
2018-02-10 15:27:24.211  INFO 14692 --- [           main] c.i.S.SpringBootSpringDataJpaApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-02-10 15:27:24.252  INFO 14692 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@221af3c0: startup date [Sat Feb 10 15:27:24 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
Sat Feb 10 15:27:24 IST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Sat Feb 10 15:27:25 IST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Sat Feb 10 15:27:25 IST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Sat Feb 10 15:27:25 IST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Sat Feb 10 15:27:25 IST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Sat Feb 10 15:27:25 IST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Sat Feb 10 15:27:25 IST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Sat Feb 10 15:27:25 IST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Sat Feb 10 15:27:25 IST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Sat Feb 10 15:27:25 IST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2018-02-10 15:27:25.131  INFO 14692 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-02-10 15:27:25.148  INFO 14692 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2018-02-10 15:27:25.241  INFO 14692 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2018-02-10 15:27:25.244  INFO 14692 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-02-10 15:27:25.247  INFO 14692 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2018-02-10 15:27:25.302  INFO 14692 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2018-02-10 15:27:25.501  INFO 14692 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2018-02-10 15:27:25.685  INFO 14692 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-02-10 15:27:25.705  WARN 14692 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'registrationService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.irs.repository.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2018-02-10 15:27:25.705  INFO 14692 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-02-10 15:27:25.712  INFO 14692 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-02-10 15:27:25.796 ERROR 14692 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field userRepository in com.service.RegistrationService required a bean of type 'com.repository.UserRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.repository.UserRepository' in your configuration.
```

*****************UserRepository.java**********************

```
package com.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.entity.UserEntity;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, String>{

}
```

****-------------------RegisterService------------******

```
@Service
public class RegistrationService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public String registerUser(User user) throws Exception{
        validateUser(user);

        UserEntity userEntity=userRepository.findOne(user.getUserId());
        ------ ---- ------ --------- -   ------------- ------------

}}
```

***---------------SpringBootMain Class-----------------------****

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="com")
@PropertySource(value={"classpath:configuration.properties"})

public class SpringBootSpringDataJpaApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootSpringDataJpaApplication.class, args);
    }
```

Comment: Can any one help me out.

Comment: How does your package structure look like? Probably you can remove scanBasePackages

Comment: Yes its under correct package structure but as per your suggestion when I removed scanBasePackages. It worked,,,,,,
Thank you.

Comment: But how does it work when we remove scanBasePackages?

Comment: @Simon Martinelli
But when I run the program itis not detecting 
RegistrationService service = (RegistrationService)applicationContext.getBean("registrationService");

Comment: If your SpringBootSpringDataJpaApplication is in the top most package it will find all beans. Why do you use the applicationContext? You can inject all the beans

Comment: Error is like below  Exception org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'registrationService' available

Comment: If your SpringBootSpringDataJpaApplication is in the top most package it will find all beans. Why do you use the applicationContext? You can inject all the beans

Comment: yes its top most package. I created new project and run but still
 RegistrationService service = (RegistrationService)applicationContext.getBean("registrationService");

Comment: In above service is "null". That is NoSuchBeanDefinitionException- while I log the null.